# How to present videos for Google Bot

Tags: google-search, seo, googlebot

i have a website which streams Flash Videos. For Google i have a special page due to using AJAX for normal Users (see [articles on "_escaped_fragment_"](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html) for this).

What i want to know is how i should present the Video in the Crawler optimized Page so GoogleBot can most easily recognize the video and maybe even add it to their Google Video search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a video sitemap ? Read more [here](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=80472).

Comment: Wow, exactly what i was searching for! Thanks a lot!